# How to set up a backend and frontend application in zend framework 1?

Tags: php, zend-framework, web-applications, module, bootstrapping

I have the following zend framework application

[image]

What is different is that I added another `application` tree inside a `backend` folder.

What i am trying to figure out is how to make the `backend` application aware of the main `application` classes.

For example, in the `bootstrap.php` from the main `application` tree I have a call to a method: `Application_Model_ModuleLoader::load()`

If I do the same inside the second bootstrap from the `backend` tree, it will error out `Class 'Application_Model_ModuleLoader' not found ..`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Backend` as module, `Frontend` is the same.

See my example below:

[image]